# What is "on-demand reciprocation"?

Tags: client-server, communication, distributed-computing, p2p

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_%28computing%29:

> The nature of communication between a client and server is **request and response**. This is in contrast with peer-to-peer model in which the relationship is **on-demand reciprocation**.

What is "on-demand reciprocation"?

How is it different from "request and response"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Request-response mostly is an unidirectional flow of payload data, the request is just metadata.

In a p2p system data flows in both directions. For example in bittorrent you have have an asynchronous stream of messages in each direction where messages can be both requests and responses. The asynchronous part is important that data can flow both ways continuously.

If you wanted to compare  it to HTTP then it would be like having one *[pipelined](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/HTTP_pipelining2.svg)* HTTP 1.1 connection open in each direction.